# Error in getting role of looged in user MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-roles

I am trying to get the role of currently logged in user. Here is my code

```
string[] rolesuserbelongto = Roles.GetRolesForUser();

  <roleManager enabled="true" />
```

in web.config

The error I am getting is the following

> An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'. The SQL error number is 5170 and the SqlException message is: Cannot create file 'C:******\ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
>       CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>       Creating the ASPNETDB_a59f73a02db543de9eafe5c626a03ff0 database...

How can this be resolved? Please I am new to c# mvc .

Comment: Looks much more like a db error as Code First tries to create a user db. Is this the first time your app contacts the database?

Comment: Are you using RoleProvider for Getting Roles?

Comment: Your `ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF` DB file already exists, hence something wrong happened on web.config file (post complete content to help find out your issue). If the DB is auto-generated, you need to change current behavior when checking existing DB.

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1102/aspnet-mvc-role-based-security this link is what i followed to create roles and assign roles to user.

Comment: @ste-fu no  i also have options to create role and assign role to user.

Comment: @Tetsuya i am not sure what you mean by changing current behaviour

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh no i am not. How do i do that?

Comment: @user2281415 You have to Create A Class And Inherit With Abstract Class RoleProvider